# Derivation of the Mann Whitney U normal approximation

Tags: self-study, references, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

The normal approximations for the Mann Whitney U statistic are given by [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) but there are no refrences mentioned. What are the actual derivation steps of the untied and tied case approximations? I´m interested in this mainly for learning purposes.

Answer (score 2):

[Mann and Whitney](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177730491) (1947) (the reference in the first note in the Wikipedia article) derive the mean and the variance of the U statistic and prove that the limiting distribution is normal (see section 4) by showing that all the even moments of the standardized statistic converge to those of the normal distribution. (The odd central moments are all zero.)

[Showing convergence to the normal moment sequence would not be sufficient if the mgf didn't converge in a neighborhood around zero, but for the normal it does.]